# How to create distance map in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, distance

I need to recreate maps like on picture in QGIS 3. They were created in ArcGIS 9.3. Have no idea how to do this, found no guides. The main problem are roads and rivers, because they are not specific dots, but line. Maybe some plugins? I am pretty new to GIS systems.
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details about your datasets that you are planning to use the generate the maps?

Comment: I have 3 shapefiles. 2 of them are lines (rivers and roads) and another one is polygon territory where i want to generate a map. Coordinate system and coordinates are set.

Comment: Which ArcGIS tool have you used to generate the maps? One option may be that you rasterize your vector datasets and use the Proximity (raster distance) https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/proximity.html

Comment: These maps are not mine, just for example what type of map i need

Answer (score 6):

That's a multi-step process; using `r.grow.distance` you can work natively with geodetic CRS (i.e. calculate distances and output using *meter* as units), rather than depend on the map projection units:

- `<Toolbox Search> | Rasterize (Vector to Raster)`

  - select your feature layer as `Input layer`
  - set `A fixed value to burn` to `1.0`
  - set `Output raster size units` to `Pixel`
  - set `Width/Horizontal resolution` to (at least) `1000.0`
  - set `Height/Vertical resolution` to `1.0`
  - set `Output extent` to that of your AOI layer (via the selector button to the right of th field)
  - `Run`
- `<Toolbox Search> | r.grow.distance`

  - select your feature layer as `Input input raster layer` [sic!]
  - set `Metric` to `geodetic`
  - mark `Advanced Options | Output distances in meter instead of map units`
  - `Run`
- `<Toolbox Search> | Clip raster by mask layer`

  - select the distance raster layer as `Input layer`
  - select the AOI vector layer as `Mask layer`
  - set either `Keep resolution of input raster` or `Set output file resolution`
  - `Run`